# Target specific content with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to address specific text within an element with CSS? E.g. :

`<div class="myClass">Good content --bad content--</div>`

I'd like to hide the text between `--` and the two delimiters (`--[...]--`) as well. So after all it should look like this:

`<div class="myClass">Good content </div>`

I CANNOT place the bad content within some HTML tags (technical restrictions)!

Comment: it is possible with `jQuery` but I have never heard of such thing in CSS

Comment: No, not with CSS - you'll need JS for that

Comment: Are both [text content] necessarily baked into the DOM? Acknowledging that you cannot tag the delimited content; can you affect the HTML at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is to only hide specific text for people without js enabled and you have access to source and can modify js/html/css 
then you could try to save your unsafe text in attribute and assign it by default with pseudo selector and on load of body within a script assign a class that will rewrite the pseudo selector contents:

```css
.myClass::after {
  content: attr(data-no-js);
}

.js-enabled .myClass::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script>document.body.classList.add('js-enabled');</script>
<div class="myClass" data-no-js=" --bad content--">Good content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to address specific text within an element with CSS?

No, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really select based on content as per the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

But, here's something - **experimental** - *just for fun* since you said CSS only which I don't think is possible.

**This has no cross browser support yet...and by I mean it won't work on IE or Edge. I tested it in Chrome 58 and FF 54 and all is good there.**

With that being said, [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-mask-image) says this will work for at least 89% of users.

```css
.myClass {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)14%, /** <---- Use this percentage to determine the cutoff point **/
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Good content --bad content--</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Javascript**, you can use [String replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method :

```
var str = 'Good content --bad content-- sometext';
str = str.replace(/--[^]*--/g, "");
alert(str); /* Good content sometext */
```

---

If you really don't want to use JavaScript, here's a CSS solution, but you have to adapt it to your `font-size`, I'm don't think it's the best approach though.

```css
.myClass{width:100px; height: 20px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Good content --bad content--</div>
```

Comment: This is with css?

Comment: Thanks, but JS is not an option. If the user hasn't JS enabled he'd see the whole string. And he must not.

Comment: @alve89 I am not sure if it is possible with CSS unless you modify the tags inside, which you don't want to.

Comment: @ehsan Yes, you can look below.